# interactivePopGestureRecognizer interferes with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with the same frame as the containing view controller.

When the zoom scale of the scrollview is greater than 1, swiping left to right starting from the left 50% of the screen causes the interactivePopGestureRecognizer to activate and dismiss the view controller.
This only happens when the device is in landscape. It works fine when in portrait.

Is there any special handling needed to make this gesture work normally with a scrollview?

Answer (score 3):

1、set interactivePopGestureRecognizer delegate to self (Custom UINavigationController)

```
self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
```

2、enable simultaneously recognize UIScrollView UIGestureRecognizer

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer == gestureRecognizer) {
        if ([otherGestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:UIScrollView.class]) {
            UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *)otherGestureRecognizer.view;
            if ((scrollView.contentSize.width > CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) && scrollView.contentOffset.x == 0)) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 1 step:
     @implementation UIScrollView (AllowPanGestureEventPass)

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
 if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]
      && [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]])
  {
      return YES;
  }
 else
 {
     return  NO;
 }
}
```

The 2 step:
`[_scrollView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:screenEdgePanGestureRecognizer];`